# IE7 container madness on jQuery UI button click

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

Clicking jQuery UI buttons on a page using IE7 makes the container jump.

Under the 'Order the #product name#' slideDown on the left, clicking the Quantity Required buttons makes the container move up a few pixels. I can live with this but would like to know why it's happening.

The main problem is on the right hand side. Clicking the buttons there takes the page across to the left, exposing the next floated div.

Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?!

You can see the page at http://www.thewebdes.co.uk/dev/cw/index.php.

-- edit --

Here's what I see when I click on each of the jQuery UI buttons in turn: http://www.thewebdes.co.uk/dev/cw/cw-ss.gif

Also, clicking straight onto the largest quantity takes the container across all the way as it did on the previous screenshot. Clicking back to a smaller quantity doesn't bring it back, if that gives any clues: http://www.thewebdes.co.uk/dev/cw/cw-ss2.gif

Comment: it looks fine to me i dont know what you are getting

Comment: @Val: Just added screenshot to my question, in case that helps. Thanks

Comment: Oh ok i see, did you attach anything to the click event ?

Comment: Nope, but I do check to see whether the value is '0' or not when 'Proceed' is clicked. I'm about to attach another SS to illustrate further

Comment: ok wat u can do is attache a click to it, and then scrollLeft to 0 so everytime one of the buttons is clicked it will keep it at 0 position the

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, attaching it to the buttons and the container but not luck I'm afraid. Good thinking though

Comment: `$('.tester').unbind().bind('mouseup click',function (){return false;});` where tester is in the label of the buttons u can change that

Comment: That stops the jumping, great, but it's not allowing selection of the buttons. Thanks for persevering! I'm trying things here but nothing doing so far.

Comment: well before the return false; u can do something like `$(this).attr('checked','checked'); return false;` which will select the button clicked :)

Comment: `$('.ui-button').click(function(){return false;});` is allowing selection, visually, but not actually selecting the underlying radio button

Comment: Good thinking but it'd be giving `checked` to a label, not an input... Is there an `.next()` way round that, do you think?

Comment: in theory it should :) but since the label has a for attr u can capture that if worse comes to worse :)

Comment: Done it! Thanks for all your help. I'll put it as an answer and give you a shoutout. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Val (see question comments), I've got this sorted:

The JS I'm using is:

```
$('.ui-button').click(function(){
  $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).attr('checked','checked');
  return false;
});
```

On each `ui-button` click, `return false` disables the IE7 jumping. However, it also removes the `ui-button`s ability to check the appropriate radio button. The radio buttons (naturally) have an id of what the label is `for` so I get this with `'#' + $(this).attr('for')` to build the id I need for that radio button.

Comment: u still got a problem with top :) "jumping" on the box on the left

Comment: not to mention u have disabled the scrolling on body tag which means people with small screen may not be able to see most of the box and most importantly the next step button

Comment: I'd not uploaded changes! Have now. Disabled scrolling? I've got it on mine (though I am using a new CSS reset, I may have missed it in there). The `#main` container resizes if it's too small (see lines 31-32 and 43-44 in my.js)

Answer (score 0):

if somebody still has the problem, following css formating worked for me:

```
* + html .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    position: fixed; /* Fix the jumpy behavior in IE 7*/
}
```